# flex is not honouring the children width in chrome

Tags: html, css

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.outer-item {
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
}

.bsimplelayout {
  flex: auto;
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.label {
  flex: 0 0 120.0px;
}

.field-item {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="outer-item">
    <div class="bsimplelayout">
      <div class="item">
        <label class="label">label left</label>
        <div class="field-item">
          <select class="standard" style="width:auto">
            <option value="Arapp:Administrator" title="">Arapp:Administrator</option>
            <option value="Arapp:Manager" title="">Arapp:Manager</option>
            <option value="Arapp:ManagersManaged" title="">Arapp:ManagersManaged</option>
            <option value="Arapp:PegaAPI" title="">Arapp:PegaAPI</option>
            <option value="Arapp:User" title="">Arapp:User</option>
            <option value="Arapp:UsersManaged" title="">Arapp:UsersManaged</option>
            <option value="UIRegressionFlex:ClientActivityTracking" title="">UIRegressionFlex:ClientActivityTracking</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

"item" div should have expanded till all the children.

Expected :- "item" div should have expanded till the end of all children.red border should have covered all the children.
Actual :- "item" div does not cover the children.refer the red border

Donot want to remove the flex basis of 120px added.

Comment: width: 100%; to select element

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you.Put width:100%; inside standard class.

Comment: @TemaniAfif need to understand why auto wont work as it should provide the width needed and flex should take care of wrapping the children.I am curious to know why it is breaking

Comment: the auto width of select is bigger than its container, the width of select is based on what is inside it

Answer (score 1):

There are special props **flex-grow** and **flex-shrink** witch provide behavior for elements with width more or less than parent container
Try to add flex-grow: 1; to div.item.

Comment: need to understand why auto wont work as it should provide the width needed and flex should take care of wrapping the children.I am curious to know why it is breaking

Comment: There are special props **flex-grow** and **flex-shrink** witch provide behavior for elements with width more or less than parent container

Comment: added the flex-grow on item div still i can see issue persist